# How to select a list of distinct values based on some values using linq or entity

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I want to get all the Pre_Number where all Reconcile_Status related to that Pre_Number=null. In this case there should not be any item in list.If there would be some other Pre_number for eg. 7/2018 and it has two records and Reconcile_Status  for those records is NULL then i should get one item in list that is 7/2018.

[image]

I tried

```
var NoNReconciled = context.tbl_prerelease_invoice
                           .Where(x => x.Reconcile_Status==null)
                           .Select(y => new { y.Pre_number }).Distinct().ToList();
```

But i got 6/2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your current attempt only checks that there is at least one record where `Reconcile_Status` is null, but it doesn't check that there are no records with the same `Pre_number` where `Reconcile_Status` is not null.

This should do the trick:

```
var NoNReconciled = context.tbl_prerelease_invoice
   .Where(x => x.Reconcile_Status == null && 
          !context.tbl_prerelease_invoice
          .Any(y => y.Pre_number == x.Pre_number && y.Reconcile_Status != null)
   ).Select(y => new { y.Pre_number })
   .Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: It's kinda impossible for me to debug since I don't have the context you have. I've written the code directly in the answer based on the code you provided in the question. Therefore, the fact that I now know it's a syntax error does not help me to find the problem. If you could be more specific perhaps I could help more.

Comment: ok the error is: 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extention method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found.

Comment: See, now it's clear I'm missing a closing parenthesis. edited my answer.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: @avinashSinghSandhu if an answer helped you you can [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

No need to create anonymous object for Pre_Number. Try below code

`var NoNReconciled = context.tbl_prerelease_invoice
                           .Where(x => x.Reconcile_Status==null)
                           .Select(y => y.Pre_number).Distinct().ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
context.tbl_prerelease_invoice.GroupBy(r => r.Pre_number).Where(kv => kv.All(r => r.Reconcile_Status==null)).Select(kv => kv.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Your welcome, I guess this should be better in case of performance as well as more readable. Can you mark this as a working answer?